# Keeping a process running after closing shell spawned by ide

Tags: ssh, session

This is similar to the other questions involving keeping a process open, but with a twist. The ssh shell containing the desired process is spawned by the ide instead of by me in an interactive shell.

I've tried to assign the process to my current shell using reptyr, but that fails with:

```
[-] Process 123 (bash) shares 456's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 456 has suprocesses).
Unable to attach to pid 456: Invalid argument
```

How would I keep this process running?